# How to achieve single class single responsibility java in my context

Tags: java

IF i have a class called Cheetah which has one method to draw() where i draw the cheetah using Java swing and another method called move() where i move my cheetah around in the frame.

Am I supposed to create two classes called CheetahMove and CheetahDraw in order to adhere to "single class single responsibility"?

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: In most cases, if you find yourself naming classes with verbs, you are on the wrong track.

Comment: @4EACH So far I left it as one class but i thought im not doing the single responsibility part right. Isnt is subjective as to what is the responsibility of a class?

Comment: @4EACH ohh i see, thanks

Comment: Your primary goal should be to write code that works. Don't get lost in and confused by these abstract principles that only have tangible benefits in large projects.... Know of design principles, but don't get too caught in *"how is my class showing that principle/pattern?"* questions too soon. As you code more, you'll analyze your code more and these design best practices will become a natural way to code.